# Reg URL sampled parameter in Response Assertion

Tags: jmeter

In Response Assertion, I have selected URL Sampled.

I am creating this assertion for My login page with invalid credentials. The URL sampled added was the URL of the next page ie.. Welcome page

With the assumption that, since the credentials are not valid and the page will not navigate to Welcome page, so my sample will fail.

Pls let me know if this is correct.

If not then tell me how to use the URL sampled parameter in Response Assertion.

Thanks 
Arun

Answer (score 1):

[Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y74Fj.png)

[Result tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akmHw.png)

Kindly refer the attached links Dimitri

Answer (score 0):

If you totally sure that redirect happens and URL changes (you can check it via [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener) you can use URL sampled as a field to check. Make sure you choose correct "Apply to" option as by default only main sample is being checked and you can run into a situation like

[image: Response Assertion scope]

The most commonly used approach is checking response data. Like for logged-in user page title changes to "Welcome" or "Profile" and "Log Out" links appear, etc.

Also be aware that Response Assertion treats criteria differently basing on what pattern matching rule is chosen:

- for `Equals` and `Substring` - expected criteria are considered **Strings**
- for `Contains` and `Matches` - expected criteria are considered [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/)

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more information on assertions cost, scope and use cases.

Comment: Hi Dmitri -  Thanks much for the reply. Please find my additional query posted under Answer 2. Please Guide.

Comment: Seems correct at first glance. Need to see the output of View Results Tree listener to tell for sure

Comment: Hi Dimitri - Uploaded the links in Answer 3 . Please guide

Comment: None of URLs contains `welcome` that's why you're getting assertion failure. Double check that you're really logged in, it might not be the case (I don't see any post processors for doing correlation) See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for details on how to perform login into ASP.NET applications. P.S. it's better update your initial question or use comments than to add new answers, they will be deleted by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I have tried URL sampled assertion as below

Http Sampler url used - test.com/

in the above link if i give the correct login credentials it will navigate to test.com/scripts/welcome.asp

If the credentials are incorrect then it remains in the same page test.com/ with an application error like "incorrect credentials"

In url sampled assertion i have given the condition as in the image (pls find the image link below)

please let me know if this is correct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikbyF.png)